# Mutators with no arguments

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public void doThings1(){
    this.doSomething();
    this.doSomethingElse();
    this.doThirdThing();
}

public void doThings2(){
    this.doSomethingElse();
    this.doThirdThing();
}
```

This feels like a really basic question, but are 0 argument mutators frowned upon? I feel like I rarely see methods within an object that directly manipulate one or more of the object's parameters directly in a predefined way. Perhaps (as shown above) you need to do some repeatable code sections in a different order, and so create methods for each scenario encapsulating the more finely grained methods? If this is considered bad, what is a better way of doing it, and if not, why do I never see it done?

Another example could be (incomplete)

```
public class TenGreenBottles{
    public void knockOneDown(){
        bottles--;
        round++;
   }
}
```

This changes an objects state, is exposed to the user, and takes no argument. Is this allowable? Is there a name for this sort of method, that performs a set task on an instance that changes the state and takes no argument?

Thanks

Comment: "Is this allowable?" is the wrong question.  The best thing to do is to learn why we have these "rules" and patterns, and what the benefits are in terms of readability and maintainability (the ability for someone else to change a program without introducing a bug).  Then you can start judging what impact your design decisions will have on the maintainability of your code.  Relying on rules is ultimately an inferior approach to software design.

Comment: Looking at your last example: I wouldn't have a problem with `knockOneDown()` doing `bottles--`, but I **would** probably have a problem with `round++`.  If I were reading the code of the caller, and it said `b.knockOneDown()`, I'd expect it to knock down a bottle, would it be obvious to me that this would also go to the next round?  That's the kind of thing that makes life harder for readers of your code.

Comment: So a sensible alternative would be `knockOneDownAndNextRound()` ? Assuming the round only ever advances (and must always advance) when a bottle is knocked.

Comment: That would be better.  To tell you whether that's the best design as a whole, though, I'd have to see a bigger part of the picture.  And my experience is "toy" code often doesn't do a good job of demonstrating what the best design approaches are.  This is a complex topic, and it's one I've spent decades studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this is very much about choosing good names that clearly convey the idea of the mutation. Naming is one of the hardest problems in programming.

I could understand a few argument-less mutators, e.g.

```
collection.sort();
collection.removeAll();
condition.invert();
editorState.undoLastAction();
textWriter.newLine();
```

On the other hand, `doSomething()` would be a confusing mutator name to me: it shows that a side effect is expected, but does not describe an internal change, if any.

Comment: Also, `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()`:)

Comment: So it's perfectly allowable but the naming has to be sensible and informative, that makes sense. Thanks!